# When a class is clicked, smoothly scroll to div after page loads

Tags: jquery

I have this code modified in a effort to smoothly scroll to a specific div on a page when a specific class is clicked on another.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a.link').on( "click", function() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $(".text").offset().top}, 1000);
    });
});
```

The problem is that when the class is clicked, the smooth scrolling begins before the new page loads. How should the code be written so that when the class is clicked, the new page loads, then the smooth scrolling to the div is executed?

Comment: Is the content loaded via AJAX, or is an entirely new page being requested?

Comment: Entirely new page.

Comment: You can not run javascript on page A to animate something on page B

Comment: Understood! Thanks, @Martijn.

Answer (score 2):

You can not run javascript on page A to animate something on page B. Javascript is excecuted on the page you are at (there are some exceptions, but yours is not one).

I've recently created a similar piece of code. I created a specific prepend to the has (`#goto_`) to remember where I want to go on the new page, and made Javascript listen to it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if( window.location.hash==="#goto_text" ){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: document.getElementById('idTargetElement').offsetTop }, 1000);
        },250);
    }
});
<a href="/targetpage#goto_text">example anchor</a>
```

This snippet will run when you load a page (e.g. when you arrive at page B) and then checks wether the hash is set to a specific text. If so, wait 250ms before scrolling so the page can load a bit first.

*There might me some easier looking options, but'll you'll find this to be easier to control in various settings. You could e.g. change the timeout to `window.load()`, or change other timings.*

Comment: Thanks, for that response, @Martijn! The next page will smoothly scroll if I remove "$('a.link').on( "click", function() {". However, I wanted it to do so when the class "a.link" is clicked from another.

Comment: Please explain in dummy steps. You are at Page A, click a link, and then?

Comment: Sure, thing! When the class is clicked on page A, page B loads, then the smooth scrolling to the div is executed on page B.

Comment: Great. That is what my example does. Drop your onclick, add and make my snippet work and it should do as you want

Comment: I can't use hashes. Sorry, I should have mentioned that from the start.

Comment: Then you end up in more complex situations. Most of them are not pretty and can think of an easy one of the top of my head

Comment: Okay, then we'll just leave it at that! I do appreciate your time and knowledge with this issue -- thank you, @Martijn!

Answer (score 0):

On the link put a hash:

```
<a href="otherpage.html#elementID">Jump</a>
```

And on other page, you can do:

```
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
}, 1000);
```

On other page, you should have element with id set to elementID to scroll to. Of course you can change the name of it.